# Clustering annotations with Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm trying to implement clustering in Mapbox for iOS and literally using [this example from Mapbox website](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/)

It works fine, but I'd like to be able to use simple MGLAnnotations to place on the map and cluster them together if they are too close.

I [read here](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.5.4/Classes/MGLShapeSource.html#/MGLShapeSource) that MGLShapeSource not only accepts external geoJSON, but other sources, such as polylines and annotations. But when I feed it with annotations array no clustering occur, I just see bunch of my  markers from my annotations array:

`let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredParkings", shapes: annotationsArray, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: 20])`

When I swap the source back to geoJSON everything works again for clusters. 
Btw there are no errors or warnings.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have a working example of Mapbox clustering with MGLAnnotations rather than geoJSON source file?

https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.0/Classes/MGLShapeSource.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research on this not too long ago and it didn't seem to be possible on iOS. [Here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5814) is the suggestion on github that is still open. [Here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7821) is another issue about how it wasn't mentioned in the documentation but has since been added.

Comment: yeah, I found that as well. Thank you. Guess we will have to wait.

Comment: Has this changed as of 2019?

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have a working example of Mapbox clustering with MGLAnnotations rather than geoJSON source file?

Given a Style

```
let style: MGLStyle
```

1) Build/Get your [MGLPointFeature]

2) Build a MGLShapeSource

```
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER_A", features: YOUR_ MGLPointFeature_ARRAY, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: YOUR_WIDTH])
style.addSource(source)
```

3) Build a style for the marker when it's not clustered

```
let markerLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER_B", source: source)
    markerLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "MARKER_IDENTIFIER")
    markerLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster != YES")
style.setImage(UIImage(named: "MARKER_IMAGE")!, forName: "MARKER_IDENTIFIER")
```

4) Build a style for the cluster

```
let clusterLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER_C", source: source)
    clusterLayer.textColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white)
    clusterLayer.textFontSize = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSNumber(value: Double(YOUR_WIDTH) / 2.5))
    clusterLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
    clusterLayer.textOffset = NSExpression(forConstantValue: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.2))
    clusterLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster == YES")
    style.setImage(UIImage(named: "CLUSTER_IMAGE")!, forName: "CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER")
```

5) You can use Stops features. This will let you change cluster image based on clustering count change.

```
let stops = [
        10: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "CLUSTER_IMAGE"),
        50: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ANOTHER_CLUSTER_IMAGE")
    ]
```

6) Use expressions to set each cluster's image based on defined stops and display the point count over the corresponding image

```
let defaultShape = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER")
    clusterLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(format: "mgl_step:from:stops:(point_count, %@, %@)", defaultShape, stops)
    clusterLayer.text = NSExpression(format: "CAST(point_count, 'NSString')")
```

7) Add layers to the Style

```
style.addLayer(markerLayer)
style.addLayer(clusterLayer)
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Explain teh code, why we do this and so forth, then I will award you the bounty

Comment: Source explaining the second part of the code: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering-with-images/

Comment: I dont think this is the solution most of us are looking for

Comment: This is the solution that answers this question: "Does anyone have a working example of Mapbox clustering with MGLAnnotations rather than geoJSON source file?":

Maybe you are looking for something else.

Comment: @SergioAndreotti please, load work project to GitHub for  Mapbox clustering with MGLAnnotations rather than geoJSON source file.

Comment: @SergioAndreotti so it's not possible to have my own AnnotationView? Like e.g. to display an image directly on the map if not clustered?

Comment: This solution does not work for me anyone else has this working?